# RVM won't create gemset for a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

`RVM` doesn't seem to be automagically creating a new `gemset` for a newly cloned `git` based `rails` project as it did for other projects when `cd`ing into the project folder. I get this message:

```
ruby-2.2.4 is not installed.
```

I am using `ruby-2.3.1` and have set it as the default and that is the only `ruby` version I installed using `rvm`. Why am I getting that error message? I am on a `MAC` (Sierra OS) if that matters.

It started happening randomly as soon as I cloned a new project. I don't see `ruby-2.2.4` being mentioned in the `gemfile` or the `gemspec`. Where is it picking it from?

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the whole error message you get when trying to run `bundle install` it'll be easier to say for certain, but I'm assuming one of the gems in your gemfile requires Ruby version 2.2.4.

Just type in

```
rvm install 2.2.4
```

Then run `bundle install` again and all should be well, assuming no other errors.

You may need to switch which version of Ruby you're using based on which project you're in, just use

```
rvm use 2.4.0

rvm use 2.2.4
```

etc.

Comment: I don't get the error while running `bundle install`. I get it when I `cd` into the project folder. For the other projects I was seeing `ruby-2.3.1@ProjectName` gemset created as soon as I did `cd` into the project folder. In this case, I was able to manually create a new gemset as `ruby-2.3.1@ProjectName` and didn't face any issues but still left me wondering why I got the message in the first place.

Comment: No, because the same project worked on `ruby-2.3.1` on `Ubuntu` on a non-`rvm` environment. Is there a way to know the `ruby` versions required by every `gem`?

Comment: There is probably a command but I can't find it after some curosry googling... If it is telling you that ruby 2.2.4 is not installed, I'd strongly suggest taking the 5 seconds to type in 'rvm 2.2.4'